# Weird Behaviour on wait() and notifyAll()

Tags: java, multithreading

I found myself puzzled with this behaviour for wait() and notifyAll():

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Producer implements Runnable {

    Queue<Integer> sharedMessages;
    Integer i = 0;
    Producer(Queue<Integer> sharedMessages) {
        this.sharedMessages = sharedMessages;
    }

    public void produce(Integer i) {
        synchronized (sharedMessages){
            System.out.println("Producing message " + i);
            this.sharedMessages.add(i);
        }
    }

    public void run(){
        synchronized (sharedMessages) {
            while (i < 100) {
                produce(i++);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
class Consumer implements Runnable{

    Queue<Integer> sharedMessages;
    Consumer(Queue<Integer> sharedMessages) {
        this.sharedMessages = sharedMessages;
    }

    public void consume() {
        synchronized (sharedMessages) {
                System.out.println(sharedMessages.remove() + " consumed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName().toString());
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized (sharedMessages){
            while(sharedMessaged.size() > 0){
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " going to consume");
                consume();
                try {
                    sharedMessages.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + ": I was interrupted from my sleep!");
                }
                sharedMessages.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I'm creating the threads:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Integer> sharedMessages = new LinkedList<>();

        new Thread(new Producer(sharedMessages)).start();

        new Thread(new Consumer(sharedMessages)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(sharedMessages)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(sharedMessages)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(sharedMessages)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(sharedMessages)).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(sharedMessages)).start();
    }

}
```

The output looks something like this:

```
Producing message 0
Producing message 1
...
Producing message 98
Producing message 99
Thread-6 going to consume
0 consumed by Thread-6
Thread-5 going to consume
1 consumed by Thread-5
Thread-4 going to consume
2 consumed by Thread-4
Thread-3 going to consume
3 consumed by Thread-3
Thread-2 going to consume
4 consumed by Thread-2
Thread-1 going to consume
5 consumed by Thread-1
```

And then the application keeps running, without consumers consuming any messages after 5.

Since `wait()` and `notifyAll()` are created on the same monitor, `sharedMessages`, and the while loop keeps on running, shouldn't the consumer threads keep on running, alternatively consuming messages?

NOTE: This question is NOT about a Bounded Blocking Queue / typical Producer Consumer. I'm trying to gain a better understanding of `wait()` and `notifyAll` and this behaviour caught my attention. I am probably missing something here, and I am looking for answers pointing out what I am missing and NOT a certain another way of doing it.

Comment: *"And then the application keeps running, without consumers consuming any messages."* But in your example output the consumers consume? I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @akuzminykh - Not all messages are consumed. Application is stuck, without all messages getting consumed

Comment: Why are you waiting unconditionally in `Consumer.run()`? That makes no sense. Consumers should only wait if there is nothing to consume. And your producer should use `notifyAll` when it has put something in the queue to wake up consumers. It would also be highly advisable to move the while-loop out of the synchronized block.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I tried it both ways, removing the while true, and consumers consuming only when size is greater than zero, it leads to same output.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with _"I tried it both ways"_. Your current code is producing its output, because all your consumers will consume at most one item and then wait unconditionally and there is nothing to wake them up. The behaviour you see is expected for the code you have written, as the only notifyAll calls happens by consumers **after** their unconditional wait, so in essence never (except under spurious wake ups). In addition, your overly large synchronized blocks hinder the threads from running concurrently.

Comment: Your `Producer` thread locks the queue, then add 100 messages without ever releasing the lock, and then finally releases the lock, without ever notifying anyone. Your 6 `Consumer` threads will each consume a message, then call `wait()`. At this point, the `Producer` thread has ended, and the 6 `Consumer` threads are waiting. Who did you envision would be notifying them to wake them up?

Comment: Mark has explained what the cause of the problem is. After your edit with *"[...] I am looking for answers pointing out what I am missing and NOT a certain another way of doing it."* let me put it this way: Not a single consumer reaches the `notifyAll` call, so the program gets stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Producer` thread locks the queue, then adds 100 messages without ever releasing the lock, and finally releases the lock before terminating, without ever notifying anyone.

Your 6 `Consumer` threads will each consume a message, then call `wait()`.

At this point, the `Producer` thread has ended, and the 6 `Consumer` threads are waiting.

Who did you envision would be notifying them to wake them up?

Answer (score 2):

Your current code is producing its output, because all your consumers will consume at most one item - depending on if they can run before or after your producer - and then they will wait unconditionally. There is nothing to wake them up, so they won't run again.

So, the behaviour you see is expected for the code you have written, as the only `notifyAll()` calls happens by consumers after their unconditional wait, so in essence never (except under spurious wake ups). In addition, your overly large synchronized blocks hinder the threads from running concurrently.

The primary changes you need to make are:

- Reduce the size of your synchronized blocks (ideally it should only cover producing or consuming a single item)
- Do not wait unconditionally, only wait when there are no items in the queue and the producer is still active (you will need a way to signal the producer is done)
- Have the producer call `notifyAll()` after each item (alternatively, call `notify()` after each item, and `notifyAll()` after all items have been produced).

Comment: good points, adding a notify() on producer part is a good idea - do you think a wait() would be required on producer as well?

Comment: @AbhinandanDubey A wait on the producer is only necessary if you have a bounded queue and the queue is full (and in that case, consumers will also need to call `notifyAll` after consuming an item), otherwise it only complicates things and reduces throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got two good answers, but if you want to compare your next solution to something, here's some code I had wrote a while ago for a simple example.  It's lightly tested but seems to work OK.

Notice instead of a `Queue` I implement my own circular buffer.  It does the same thing, but its implementation is a little closer to what you might see in some low level (and optimized) object.

```
public class ProducerConsumer {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      CircularBuffer buffer = new CircularBuffer();
      Counter producer1 = new Counter( buffer, 1000 );
      Counter producer2 = new Counter( buffer, 2000 );
      Counter producer3 = new Counter( buffer, 3000 );
      Counter producer4 = new Counter( buffer, 4000 );
      
      ExecutorService exe = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      
      exe.execute( producer1 );
      exe.execute( producer2 );
      exe.execute( producer3 );
      exe.execute( producer4 );
      
      Printer consumer = new Printer( buffer );
      exe.execute( consumer );
      
      Thread.sleep( 100 );// wait a bit
      exe.shutdownNow();
      exe.awaitTermination( 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
   }
}

// Producer
class Counter implements Runnable {
   private final CircularBuffer output;
   private final int startingValue;

   public Counter(CircularBuffer output, int startingValue) {
      this.output = output;
      this.startingValue = startingValue;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
         try {
            for( int i = startingValue; ; i++ ) 
               output.put(i);
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // exit...
         }
   }
   
}

class CircularBuffer {
   private final int[] buffer = new int[20];
   private int head;
   private int count;
   public synchronized void put( int i ) throws InterruptedException {
      while( count == buffer.length ) wait();// full
      buffer[head++] = i;
      head %= buffer.length;
      count++;
      notifyAll();
   }
   public synchronized int get() throws InterruptedException {
      while( count == 0 ) wait(); // empty
      int tail = (head - count) % buffer.length;
      tail = (tail < 0) ? tail + buffer.length : tail;
      int retval = buffer[tail];
      count--;
      notifyAll();
      return retval;
   }
}

// Consumer
class Printer implements Runnable {
   private final CircularBuffer input;

   public Printer(CircularBuffer input) {
      this.input = input;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
         try {
            for( ;; ) 
               System.out.println( input.get() );
         } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // exit...
         }
   }
}
```